# Migrate from Kontakt 5 to 6 in Logic Pro X

Tags: logic-pro

I purchased NI Kontakt 5 in 2017, and I upgraded to 6 just today in Oct 2020.

I have a bunch of Logic Pro X projects using Kontakt 5 instruments, and I want to migrate them to Kontakt 6 and then uninstall Kontakt 5 to save some disk space.

How do I mass-convert my Kontakt 5 tracks to Kontakt 6?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track-by-track conversion is possible by first saving the Kontakt 5 instrument as an `*.aupreset` file then switch to Kontakt 6 and load that file.

To save a Kontakt instrument as an `*.aupreset` file,

1. click on the instrument rack in the track strip to open the instrument settings window;
2. click on the drop-down menu bar to the right of the blue track-enable indicator button;
3. click "Save As" option and save the instrument.

To load the just-saved instrument in Kontakt 6, go to the same drop-down menu and click the "Load..." option and select the just-saved `*.aupreset` file.

Mass-convert don't seem possible, as the "bundle identifier" of the main "Info.plist" are different for 2 versions: `Kontakt 5.MusicDevice.component` and `Kontakt.MusicDevice.component`. You can check them in `/Library/Audio/Plug-Ins/Components`

So while it's a shame there's no easy way to mass convert K5 to K6, there's hope K6 to K7 conversion will be viable in the future if NI developers drop version number entirely in the bundle identifier.

Comment: I’m not a programmer, but plenty of folks on this site are (as it’s a descendant of Stack Overflow). Surely somebody can come up with a bit of terminal code to manipulate logic files to replace the Kontakt 5 references with Kontakt 6. Or maybe I’m wrong, because all the plugin settings might be different too, which would cause errors...

Comment: @BobBroadley I don't think "terminal code" is feasible, as terminal shells function by executing external programs and Logic is probrably not installing any additional programs. I've probed Logic project data using the [file(1)](https://man.freebsd.org/file) command and it doesn't show recognizable structure. Apple Script might be possible, but I haven't tried.

Comment: @DannyNiu Can you please explain how to save the Kontakt 5 instrument as an `*.aupreset`? I can't find that information anywhere.

Comment: @jordanbtucker Done.